# Fade image in and fade out based on another element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am working on an R markdown script. I want to fade in an image as I scroll down the page and fade out. The image should fade in as the code chunk that produced it comes into the viewport and then fade out as the code chunk scrolls out of the viewport.

So far, I've only been able to get it to scroll out but haven't figured out how to get it to scroll in. Here is what I have so far:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  // Setting: Start fading halfway up the page
  var startPos = 0.2;
  
  var x = $('.prefade').scrollTop();


  // Cache window object
  var $w = $(window);

  // Basically, we go through each element and check its relative position within the viewport
  $('.prefade').each(function() {

    // Get current relative position in viewport, based on the top edge
    var pos = $(this).offset().top - $w.scrollTop();

    // Get viewport height
    var vh = $w.height();

    if (pos < vh * startPos) {
      // If element has past the starting threshold, we fade it
      $('.fade').css('opacity', pos / (vh * startPos) * 1);
    } else {
      $('.fade').css('opacity', 1);
    }
  });
});
```

I've place the code chunk inside a div with a class of "prefade", which I use to determine when to fade in and fade out the image placed inside a div with class "fade". This is what it looks like:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  // Setting: Start fading halfway up the page
  var startPos = 0.2;
  
  var x = $('.prefade').scrollTop();


  // Cache window object
  var $w = $(window);

  // Basically, we go through each element and check its relative position within the viewport
  $('.prefade').each(function() {

    // Get current relative position in viewport, based on the top edge
    var pos = $(this).offset().top - $w.scrollTop();

    // Get viewport height
    var vh = $w.height();

    if (pos < vh * startPos) {
      // If element has past the starting threshold, we fade it
      $('.fade').css('opacity', pos / (vh * startPos) * 1);
    } else {
      $('.fade').css('opacity', 1);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
h1 {
    margin-bottom: 0.3rem;
    font-weight: 800;
    display: block;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-block-start: 0.67em;
    margin-block-end: 0.67em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
}

#TOC {
    width: 50%;
    background: #eee;
    opacity: 0.7;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    margin: 0 0 0.5em 0.5em;
}

.container-fluid.main-container {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.hljs {
    color: #c5c8c6;
}

.hljs {
    display: block;
    overflow-x: auto;
    padding: 0.5em;
    background: #1d1f21;
}

pre code {
    color: whitesmoke;
    background: inherit;
    white-space: inherit;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
}

code {
    border-radius: 2px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    color: #5e5e5e;
    background: #FFF7DD;
    border: 1px solid #fbf0cb;
    padding: 0 2px;
}

code, kbd, pre, samp {
    font-family: "Consolas", menlo, monospace;
    font-size: 92%;
}

code {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

code {
    font-family: monospace;
}

#body-inner pre {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}

pre {
    padding: 1rem;
    margin: 2rem 0;
    background: #1d1f21;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 2px;
    line-height: 1.15;
}

pre {
    position: relative;
    color: #ffffff;
}

pre {
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}

body {
    color: var(--MAIN-TEXT-color) !important;
}

body {
    font-size: 16px !important;
    color: #323232 !important;
    text-align: justify;
    word-wrap: break-word
}

body {
    font-family: "Work Sans", "Helvetica", "Tahoma", "Geneva", "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.6;
    font-size: 18px !important;
}

body {
    background: #fff;
    color: #777;
}

body {
    font-size: 1.05rem;
    line-height: 1.7;
}

:root {
    --MAIN-TEXT-color: #323232;
    --MAIN-TITLES-TEXT-color: #5e5e5e;
    --MAIN-LINK-color: #599a3e;
    --MAIN-LINK-HOVER-color: #3f6d2c;
    --MAIN-ANCHOR-color: #599a3e;
    --MENU-HEADER-BG-color: #74b559;
    --MENU-HEADER-BORDER-color: #9cd484;
    --MENU-SEARCH-BG-color: #599a3e;
    --MENU-SEARCH-BOX-color: #84c767;
    --MENU-SEARCH-BOX-ICONS-color: #c7f7c4;
    --MENU-SECTIONS-ACTIVE-BG-color: #1b211c;
    --MENU-SECTIONS-BG-color: #222723;
    --MENU-SECTIONS-LINK-color: #ccc;
    --MENU-SECTIONS-LINK-HOVER-color: #e6e6e6;
    --MENU-SECTION-ACTIVE-CATEGORY-color: #777;
    --MENU-SECTION-ACTIVE-CATEGORY-BG-color: #fff;
    --MENU-VISITED-color: #599a3e;
    --MENU-SECTION-HR-color: #18211c;
}


.hljs::selection, .hljs span::selection {
    background: #b7b7b7;
}
.hljs::selection, .hljs span::selection {
    background: #373b41;
}


.triangle {
  position: fixed;
  left:1015px;
  margin-bottom:0;
  top:60vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom:350px solid #373b41;
  border-left: 350px solid transparent;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.fade {
  position: relative;
  left:600px;
  opacity: 1;
  width:600px;
  z-index: 9;
}

#scatterplot {
  position:relative;
  top: -60vh;
  z-index:-1
}
```

```html
<div id="plotting-data" class="section level2">
<h2><span class="header-section-number">3.2</span> Plotting data</h2>
<div id="codescatter" class="prefade">
<pre class="r"><code class="hljs">ggplot(chocolate, aes(x= Review.Date, y = Rating, color = Cocoa.Percent)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_jitter() +
  geom_smooth(method = <span class="hljs-string">'lm'</span>)+
  scale_color_continuous(low = <span class="hljs-string">"#b69885"</span>, high = <span class="hljs-string">"#763411"</span>)+
  theme_economist()+
  theme(legend.key.width = unit(<span class="hljs-number">5</span>, <span class="hljs-string">"lines"</span>))</code></pre>
</div>
<div id="scatterplot" class="fade" style="opacity: 1;">
<p><img src="https://i.imgur.com/Kdarrua.png" width="900" height="550"></p>
</div>

<p>dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text</p>
<p>dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text</p>
<p>dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text</p>
<p>dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text</p>
<p>dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text</p>
<p>dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text</p>
<p>dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text</p>
<p>dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text</p>
<p>dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text</p>
<p>dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text</p>
<p>dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text</p>
<p>dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text</p>
<p>dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text</p>
<p>dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text</p>
<p>dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text</p>
<p>dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text</p>
<p>dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text</p>
<p>dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text</p>
<p>dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text</p>
<p>dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text</p>
<p>dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text</p>
<p>dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text</p>
<p>dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text</p>
<p>dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text</p>
<div class="triangle" style="color:#ffffff" id="corner">
</div>
</div>
```

[How it looks so far](https://i.imgur.com/DLAvtJ8.mp4)

Anyone with any suggestions to both fade in as the code chunk comes into view and then fade out as the code chunk goes out of view?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you use `.prefade` position to change '.fade' opacity, and just make a little change on your js code, hope it helps.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  // Setting: Start fading halfway up the page
  var startPos = 0.2;
  
  var x = $('.prefade').scrollTop();


  // Cache window object
  var $w = $(window);

  // Basically, we go through each element and check its relative position within the viewport
  $('.prefade').each(function() {

    // Get current relative position in viewport, based on the top edge
    var pos = $(this).offset().top - $w.scrollTop();
    

    if (pos < startPos) {
      $('.fade').css('opacity', 1 - Math.abs(pos - startPos) / $(this).height())
    } else {
      $('.fade').css('opacity', 1);
    }
  });
});
```

For full code `https://codepen.io/doichithhe/pen/PoZxazr`

Comment: This still doesn't fade in as the element comes into the viewport.

Comment: Then i think you should pick out 2 threshold, top and bottom.
From element scrollTop to topThreshold, opacity will be changed from 0 to 1.
From bottomThreshold to (element scrollTop + element height), will be 1 to 0. 
That what i think :)